# Збрасываеться переменная при запуске игры. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там где Monster и Player после запуска игры в редакторе эти переменные збрасываються и там пишет None.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class pigeon_ai : MonoBehaviour
{
public NavMeshAgent Monster;
public GameObject Player;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Monster = gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Monster.SetDestination(Player.transform.position);
    float Dist_Player = Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position, gameObject.transform.position);
    if (Dist_Player < 1f)
    {
        ReloadLevel();
    }
}

void ReloadLevel()
{
    int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex);
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что в иерархии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка которая появляется при запуске.

Comment: Вы определитесь, в редакторе вы хотите определить значения для `Monster` и `Player` или в скрипте? Если в редакторе, удалите код метода `Start`. Если в скрипте, сделайте поля приватными. А то у вас и там и там.